# Create a vector using rep() and seq()

Tags: r, sequence, seq, rep

How to create a vector sequence of:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 6 7 8 7 8
```

I tried to use:

```
2:8+rep(0:6,each=6)
```

but the result is:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .... 12 13 14
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `unlist(Map(":", 2:7,8))`

Comment: or `sapply(2:7, function(i)seq(i, 8))`

Comment: Similarly, `sapply(7:2, function(x) seq(to = 8,length.out = x))`

Comment: @Sotos, that's the same as `sapply(2:7, seq, 8)` but you'd still need to `unlist`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes I know. It's a matter of preference

Comment: `head(sequence(7:1) + rep(1:7, 7:1), -1)`

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
library(purrr)
unlist(map(2:7, ~.x:8))

# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 6 7 8 7 8
```

and a little function in base R:

```
funky_vec <- function(from,to){unlist(sapply(from:(to-1),`:`,to))}
funky_vec(2,8)
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 6 7 8 7 8
```

Comment: unlist(lapply(2:7,function(x){x:8})) works also without an additional package

Comment: yes, I wanted to put the pretty answer first, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
x = 2
VecSeq = c(x:8)

while (x < 7) {
    x = x + 1
    calc = c(x:8)
    VecSeq = c(VecSeq, calc)
}

VecSeq # Your desired vector
```

Answer (score 0):

This is made really easy with `sequence` (since R 4.0.0):

```r
sequence(7:2, 2:7)
#  [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 6 7 8 7 8
```